# CSS Primer - Float vs Liquid Layout

Tags: css, terminology

Is there a different between a float vs liquid layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float can be both liquid and fixed...

float is just a css property which can be used for both liquid and fixed layouts..

Answer (score 0):

Float refers to how you position an element while liquid layout refers to how the layout can expand and adjust as the browser window resizes. Float positioning can be used in any kind of layout.